# Unable to connect via password authentication to postgresql on amazon linux

Tags: postgresql

I am using this reference to install postgres-12 on amazon linux: https://techviewleo.com/install-postgresql-12-on-amazon-linux/

The core of it is:

```
sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg.repo<<EOF
[pgdg12]
name=PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64
baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
EOF

sudo yum makecache

sudo yum install postgresql12 postgresql12-server

sudo /usr/pgsql-12/bin/postgresql-12-setup initdb

sudo systemctl enable --now postgresql-12

systemctl status postgresql-12
```

This installation does work: `postgresql` is up.  But it only allows local connection via the `postgres` user.  I have been trying to get `md5` [password] auth running and it is not working.

```
]$ psql -U pubkey
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "pubkey"
```

Here is the pg_hba.conf: notice it does have

```
  local  all      all          md5
```

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
local  all      all          md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

I have restarted postgres after adding that `md5` line:

```
sudo systemctl stop  postgresql-12
sudo systemctl start  postgresql-12
```

But password auth is still not working.   What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do this part of tutorial?:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'StrongPassword'"
ALTER ROLE
```

If so to use password(md5) authentication you will need to do:

```
psql -d postgres -U postgres -h localhost
```

Without `-h` you are connecting via socket(local in pg_hba.conf) and using `peer` auth.

I would also comment out/remove/or move to bottom of IPv4 local connections :

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident`

In pg_hba.conf first match wins, so if you are connecting via `localhost`(host in pg_hba.conf) and ipv4 it will be looking for `ident` auth.

It is all explained here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html